# How to check whether one number range from one file is the subset of other number range from other file?

Tags: shell, awk

I'm trying to find out whether range1 numbers [both columns a and b] are the subset or lying between range2's columns [both columns b and c].

range1

```
a        b
15       20
 8       10
37       44
32       37
```

range2

```
    a       b       c
    chr1    6       12
    chr2    13      21
    chr3    31      35
    chr4    36      45
```

output:

```
a       b       c
chr1    6       12       8       10
chr2    13      21       15      20
chr4    36      45       37      44
```

I wanted to compare range1[a] with range2[b] and range1[b] with range2[c]. One to all comparison.

For example in the first run: the first row of range-1 with all other rows of range-2. But range1[a] should be compared only with range2[b] and similarly, range1[b] should be compared only with range2[c]. Based on this only I have written a criteria :

```
lbs[i] && lbsf1[j] <= ubs[i] && ubsf1[j] >= lbs[i] && ubsf1[j] <= ubs[i]

r1[a] r2[b] r1[b] r2[c]
15 > 6      20 < 12     False
15 > 13     20 < 21     True
15 > 31     20 < 35     False
15 > 36     20 < 45     False
```

I have tried to learn from this code [which is working if we wanted to check if a single number is lying in a specific range], therefore I tried modifying the same for two both numbers. But did not work, I'm feeling I'm not able to read the second file properly.

Code: [reference but little modified]

```
    #!/bin/bash

awk -F'\t' '
# 1st pass (fileB): read the lower and upper range bounds
FNR==NR { lbs[++count] = $2+0; ubs[count] = $3+0; next }
# 2nd pass (fileA): check each line against all ranges.
{ lbsf1[++countf1] = $1+0; ubsf1[countf1] = $2+0;

        for(i=1;i<=count;++i)
                {
                        for(j=1;j<=countf1;++j)
                        {
                        if (lbsf1[j] >= lbs[i] && lbsf1[j] <= ubs[i] && ubsf1[j] >= lbs[i] && ubsf1[j] <= ubs[i])
                                { print lbs[i]"\t"ubs[i]"\t"lbsf1[j]"\t"ubsf1[j] ; next }
                        }
                }
}
' range2 range1
```

This code gave me output:

```
6       12      8       10
6       12      8       10
6       12      8       10
```

Thank you.

Comment: If these are [bed](https://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat.html#format1) files, range1 file is missing the chromosome. Also, have you checked [bedtools](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- input files do not have `a b` nor `a b c` as the first line (we can modify the proposed code if these lines really do exist in the data)
- lines in `range2` do not have leading white space (as shown in the provided sample)
- while not demonstrated by the small sample provided, going to assume that a row from `range1` may 'match' with multiple rows from `range2` and that we want to print all matches (we can modify the proposed code if we need to stop processing a `range1` row once we find the first 'match')

Sample data:

```
$ cat range1
15      20
 8      10
37      44
32      37

$ cat range2
chr1    6       12
chr2    13      21
chr3    31      35
chr4    36      45
chr15   36      67             # added to demonstrate multi-match for range1 [ 37 , 44 ]
```

Issues with current code:

- loads the `range1` data into an array and then loops over this (ever growing array) for each line read from `range1`; this array is unnecessary as we just need to process the **current** row from `range1`
- the dual loop logic is aborted (`; next`) upon printing the first matching set of records; this premature cancellation means we only see the first match ... over and over; the `; next` can be removed
- the `range2[a]` column is not captured during `range2` input processing so we're unable to display this column in the final output

Updating OP's current code to address these issues:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="\t" }

FNR==NR { chromo[++count]=$1
          lbs[count]=$2
          ubs[count]=$3
          next
        }

        { lb=$1
          ub=$2

          for (i=1;i<=count;++i)
              if ( lb >= lbs[i] && lb <= ubs[i] && ub >= lbs[i] && ub <= ubs[i] )
                 print chromo[i],lbs[i],ubs[i],lb,ub
        }
' range2 range1
```

This generates:

```
chr2    13      21      15      20
chr1    6       12       8      10
chr4    36      45      37      44
chr15   36      67      37      44
```

If the output needs to be sorted we could modify the `awk` code to store the results in another array and then during `END {...}` processing sort and print the array.  But for simplicity sake we'll just pipe the output to `sort`, eg:

```
$ awk ' BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } FNR==NR ....' range2 range1 | sort -V
chr1    6       12       8      10
chr2    13      21      15      20
chr4    36      45      37      44
chr15   36      67      37      44
```

Comment: Yes, all your assumptions are correct. and thank you so much it worked well